# Как использовать в Python скрипте значение переменной из запущенного bash скрипта через subprocess.Popen()?

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

Я пытаюсь запустить процесс в скрипте `python` через `subprocess.Popen([path])`, и сразу после запуска процесса достать его `PID`, чтобы получить в последующем `ID` окон этого процесса. Когда я делаю это напрямую, то есть вместо `path` использую путь прямиком к программе, которую хочу запустить, я просто использую то, что возвращает сам `Popen()`. Но если эта программа запускает посредством `bash` скрипта, я могу использовать только `"$$"` для получения `PID` текущего процесса. Вопрос в том, можно ли как то получить в python скрипте значение этой переменной и работать с ней внутри?

Вот фрагмент моего кода `python`:

```py
pid = subprocess.Popen([path])
path_to_sh = Path(__file__).absolute().parent
time.sleep(0.2)
id_ = os.popen(f'{path_to_sh}/getWinID.sh {pid.pid}')
# получение первого ID окна
window_id = id_.readlines()[0][:-1]
```

Вот скрипт `run.sh`, который просто запускает программу, путь к которому лежит в переменной `path` скрипта `python`, в котором я пробовал выводить текущий PID через echo. Вывести все получается, но к сожалению оно идет мимо скрипта `python`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
<абсолютный путь к программе> &
echo "$$"
```

Вот используемый bash скрипт `getWinID.sh` для получения ID'ов окон:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read line; do
  if [[ "${line}" =~ (0x)([0-9a-z]+)([ ][- ][0-9]+[ ])([0-9]*) ]]; then
    winId="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    pid="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    if [[ "${pid}" -eq "${1}" ]]; then
      WIND_IDS+=("${winId}")
    fi
  fi
done < <(wmctrl -lp)

if [ "${#WIND_IDS[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "${WIND_IDS[@]}"
fi
```

Последовательность выполнения:

`script.py` запускает -> `run.sh` запускает программу и возвращает ее `PID` в -> `script.py` передает `PID` -> `getWinID.sh` возвращает `ID` окон в -> `script.py`.

Если в переменной `path` будет путь к sh скрипту, то в переменной `pid` будет: `<Popen: returncode: None args: ...`

Я рассматривал вариант перенаправить вывод `echo` в файл, и потом его считывать в `python`. Но мне показалось, что есть более короткий и оптимальный путь решения этой задачи.

PS: Для выполнения скрипта нужна установленная утилита `wmctrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя некоторое время, поэкспериментировав, я нашел решение, в `subprocess` есть функция считывания `stdout`, и через нее можно получить все что выведено через `echo`:

```py
pid = subprocess.Popen([path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# тут будет как раз первая строка в выводе, в которой будет PID процесса.
pid = int(pid.stdout.readline()[:-1])
```

Один нюанс с `bash` скриптом, заключается в том, что нужно использовать не `$$`, а `$!`. В первом случае `PID` будет меньше на единицу, чем текущий:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
<абсолютный путь к программе> &
echo "$!"
```